# remove a instance from memory after doing "add" into a list

Tags: java, list, memory

the code is very simple:

```
  myKpi = "a";
  Data.add(myKpi);
```

and then I want to remove myKpi from memory because it has been saved in the list Data.

I have read that I can do sth like `myKpi=null`, but I don´t know if it will afect the value of `Data`.

Comment: No, `myKpi=null` will not affect the value already stored in `Data`. Why not try it yourself and see?

Comment: You can't remove it from memory since, well, it is saved in the list Data. Therefore `myKpi=null` has no meaning as long as the list contains a reference to that object.

Comment: Ummm, this is Java right? It's garbage collected, so just let the garbage collector handle it. Unless you have a burning desire to micro manage your memory like this, in which case you may want to look into unmanaged language like C++.

Comment: `Data.add(myKpi)` doesn't introduce another copy of the `String` in memory. Setting `myKpi` to `null` will make no difference.

Comment: List `Data` is itself in memory, along with all objects that it contains. It does not store copies of your items, though, only references.

Comment: `Data` violates the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

First, `myKpi` is just a reference to the instance. That means you can't "remove" `myKpi` from memory (at least not the instance it references).

Second, since the instance that is referenced by `myKpi` is added to `Data` you can't remove that instance since both references refer to the same instance.

Third, you can't manually remove an instance from the heap. All you can do is remove all references and then "ask" the JVM to do garbage collection (via `System.gc()`) which it will probably do but there's no guarantee it will be done (and what will actually be deleted).

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
Data.remove(myKpi);
```

What type of List do you use?

Comment: You could create an extra Method for like adding myKpi because in that case the variable would just exist temporarily.